# How to make model for sub-category and category for product in django?

Tags: python, django, model, categories

I have to make product model in django where when we select the the main category which is foreign key then we have to select sub category, problem is that it will show the all sub category. it have to show the sub category as per main category selected

**Main Category Model**

> Here we just have three fields

```
class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="maincategory",null=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Sub Category Model**

> here we give the Main category as foreignkey

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    main_category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.main_category.title + " - " + self.title
```

**Product Model**

> In The Product model i will give two foreign key for main and sub category

> `maincategory = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)`

> `subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sts = (
        ("PUBLISH","PUBLISH"),
        ("DRAFT","DRAFT"),
    )
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maincategory = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True,null=True,default=None)
    status = models.CharField(choices=sts,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vendor + " - " + self.title
```

So how to create model where select subcategory as per main category in admin panel django

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is have a nested subcategories, you can look into django mptt [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

or you can follow this blog post [simpleit](https://simpleit.rocks/python/django/categories-with-django-cbv/)

there is a category tutorial using django mptt. also you can further customize django mptt to limit it's depth.

Comment: Django-mptt seems a little overcomplicated for two fields.